Firefox print headers / footers doesn't print on particular website
I am using Windows 11 Home with the fire-fox 124.0.2
I have print settings available, via updating the about:config. I setup the headers and footers to my preferences.  I go to print webpages and it prints headers/footers exactly as i setup, with the exception of one online banking site.
When i attempt to print a transaction or something from that website, the print preview and print have NO headers/footers.  I do not have to close firefox, and i can go to another website, and print works printing the headers/footers.
I wouldn't think a website could modify those settings, but maybe a website can disable the headers/footers?
Any thoughts???  This is for my elderly mother and she wants to print EVERYTHING, and she doesn't understand why the Date/Time doesn't print for this particular website.  I myself am at a loss.
